Sound choppy with Kubuntu 24.04 when playing Proton games
I'm running Kubuntu 24.04 on an ASRock motherboard with a Realtek chip.  lspci identifies the chip as a ASRock Incorporation Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller and it uses the snd_hda_intel driver.  The sound seems to work fine except in some Proton games, where it will be choppy or cut in and out.
I've tried copying ~/.config/pipewire/pipewire*.conf files from /usr/share/pipewire and after doing some Googling, tried changing the default quantum rates:
default.clock.quantum       = 2048
default.clock.min-quantum   = 1024
default.clock.max-quantum   = 4096

As well as changing the default clock rates in pipewire-pulse.conf:
default.clock.allowed-rates = [ 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000, 176400, 192000 ]

However, I'm still getting choppy sound.  I don't see a "smoking gun" in the pipewire logs, so I'm thinking maybe it's Proton?
me@me-desktop:~$ journalctl --user -u pipewire -n 10 --no-pager
Aug 31 13:54:15 me-desktop pipewire[107976]: ALSA lib pcm.c:2721:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2 CARD 1}
Aug 31 13:54:15 me-desktop pipewire[107976]: spa.alsa: 'a52:1': playback open failed: No such file or directory
Aug 31 13:54:15 me-desktop pipewire[107976]: spa.alsa: 'a52:1': playback open failed: No such file or directory
Aug 31 13:54:15 me-desktop pipewire[107976]: pw.node: (alsa_output.pci-0000_0f_00.4.iec958-ac3-surround-51-53) suspended -> error (Start error: No such file or directory)
Aug 31 13:54:15 me-desktop systemd[2934]: Stopping pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service...
Aug 31 13:54:15 me-desktop pipewire[107976]: pw.node: (alsa_output.pci-0000_0f_00.4.iec958-ac3-surround-51-53) running -> error ((null))
Aug 31 13:54:15 me-desktop pipewire[107976]: Asked to handle disabled watch: 0x5a2ade327c20 31Asked to handle disabled watch: 0x5a2ade317250 26
Aug 31 13:54:15 me-desktop systemd[2934]: Stopped pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.
-- Boot 6ccec248982d4cb98e4d008cbf5ba3e2 --
Aug 31 13:55:05 me-desktop systemd[2929]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Aug 31 13:55:05 me-desktop pipewire[2943]: mod.jackdbus-detect: Failed to receive jackdbus reply: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.jackaudio.service was not provided by any .service files

This of course works fine in Windows.  Any idea why the sound would cut in and out like that?
